# Android org.json.JSONException: Cannot convert to JSON array

Tags: php, android, json, http

I am getting org.json.JSONException: Cannot convert to JSON array, heres the code:

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
     InputStream is = null;
     try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new     HttpPost("http://csddata.site11.com/json.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String read = sb.toString();    
        Log.d("HTTP", "Result = " + read);
        return read;    

     } finally {
         if (is != null) {
             is.close(); // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is// finished using it.
         } 
     }
```

Now code where im getting the error:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                MagList titleRow = new MagList();
                titleRow.title = json_data.getString("first_name");
                titleRow.page_url = json_data.getString("last_name");
                arrayOfWebData.add(titleRow);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("HTTP", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Log.d("HTTP", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        }
```

I am receiving both "Log.d" and this is what i receive through them:

```
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): ]; of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray 

05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): Failed data was:
05-24 16:44:59.721: D/HTTP(20260): "[\n{ \"firstName\":\"John\" , \"lastName\":\"Doe\" },<br> \n{ \"firstName\":\"Anna\" , \"lastName\":\"Smith\" }, \n{ \"firstName\":\"Peter\" , <br>\"lastName\": \"Jones\" }\n];"
```

Can anyone help? if you need any more info just leave a comment :)

PHP FILE:

```
<?php 
$json = '[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
];';
print json_encode($json);

?>
```

AFTER CHANGES:

```
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203): org.json.JSONException: Value [
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203): {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}, 
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203): {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"}, 
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203): {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203): ] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
05-24 17:33:17.221: W/System.err(24203):    at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:381)
```

NEW CODE:

```
// onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
            if(result != null) result = result.replace("\n","");
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                MagList titleRow = new MagList();
                titleRow.title = json_data.getString("first_name");
                titleRow.page_url = json_data.getString("last_name");
                arrayOfWebData.add(titleRow);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("HTTP", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Log.d("HTTP", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}


        aa=new FancyAdapter();
        listV.setAdapter(aa);


   }
 // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
 // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
 // a string.
 private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
     InputStream is = null;
     try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://csddata.site11.com/json.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String read = sb.toString();    
        Log.d("HTTP", "Result = " + read);
        return read;    

     } finally {
         if (is != null) {
             is.close(); // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is// finished using it.
         } 
     }        
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the ending ; is screwing it up, that isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to json_encode a string that is already json encoded in your php code. Typically you call json_encode on a php array to reformat it as a json string. since it's already a string i believe you can simply `echo($json);` instead of trying to json_encode it.

Answer (score 1):

you have following issues in current json String:

**1.** you will need to remove spaces from Json String  in PHP code before passing it to `json_encode`. valid json string is:

```
$json = '[
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
]';
print $json;
```

**2.** no need to add new line character when reading data from `BufferedReader` :

```
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
  sb.append(line);  //<<< remove \n from here
}
```

Comment: @DrDebug : *still not working* mean? can u plz update your latest code and log if u are getting any error

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the new line character (\n) in the string. Either remove it via replace from the string or don't return the response with "\n" character from your service. The JSONArray would work fine then.

EDIT: do this:

```
try{
            if(result != null) result = result.replace("\n","");
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                MagList titleRow = new MagList();
                titleRow.title = json_data.getString("first_name");
                titleRow.page_url = json_data.getString("last_name");
                arrayOfWebData.add(titleRow);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("HTTP", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Log.d("HTTP", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        }
```

EDIT2: 
just noticed you are appending "\n" to your string builder. That is the error point. The other answer is bang on. No need to do replace in the string.

EDIT3: 
replace with the following code. Remove all new line chars:

```
$json = '[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"}, {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}]';
print json_encode($json);
```